# WPF XamComboBox DisplayMemberPath with concatenated values

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, infragistics

I have the following code -

```
<igEditors:XamComboEditor ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}"
                                          Margin="5,2,5,2" Width="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInstance,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                                          >
                    <igEditors:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                                                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Id" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>                        
                    </igEditors:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
                </igEditors:XamComboEditor>
```

When I set the SelectedInstance from my viewmodel, the combobox is displaying the type of the object.  If I then make a selection, it displays correctly, but I click out of the combobox, losing focus, it reverts back to the object type. If I set the DisplayMemberPath manually to just Name, it works correctly, but I really need it to be a concatenated value for the displaymemberpath.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question was to use the ValueToDisplayTextConverter along with a custom converter.  More details can be found here -

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/77378/390782.aspx